# How to scroll text inside gesture control in Flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll

I have a a Flutter app with some widgets.

I am using `GestureDetector` widget for swiping, I have a number of widgets in a stack. Sometimes I show some text on top of the other widgets and sometimes the text is too large to fit. So I wanted to add scrolling as is a custom.

`Positioned` widget breaks the scrolling. If I remove the widget, or even remove the "top/left/right" options, it works fine!?

A reproducible example below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: StackOverflowExample()));
}

class StackOverflowExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const StackOverflowExample({super.key});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        // ignore: avoid_print
        onTap: () {
          print('tap');

        },
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            const Positioned(
              top: 50,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Text(
                  'Lot and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots ',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` with `SizedBox` for `height`,

instead of fixing `Text` widget's `maxLines` with 2.

```dart
const Center(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 150,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Text(
        '3 lines of text\nsecond line\n3rd invisible line',
        // maxLines: 2,
        ...
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Max lines is just to force the text to wrap to demonstrate that scrolling is not working. That's not real.

Comment: I have changed the example in the question to remove max lines and just have a lot of text. Scrolling still does not work

Comment: Did you wrap SingleChildScrollView with SizedBox fixing height?

Comment: I just want to use all the available space. I have added a second example which uses expanded inside a column and it still does not scroll, even without the GestureDetector

Comment: Tried the sized box instead of expanded, still does not work.

Comment: Your second example works well, without any editing. How about trying on another device?

Comment: And you can multiply String in Dart. Like Text('lots of text ' * 100).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251823/discussion-between-under-and-debug-ing).